# What do Android Studio modules produce?

Tags: android-studio, module

What do Android Studio modules produce?  e.g. a jar per module, an apk per module?

How do dependencies between modules affect these?

Or is it solely an IDE fiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are getting started I would advice you check out this page:
https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html It contains what you seek.

*"There are only a handful of files and folders generated for you, and some of them depend on whether you use Android Studio or the android tool to generate your module. As your application grows in complexity, you might require new kinds of resources, directories, and files."*
**-As in the the dev.android link I just posted above**

Comment: Thanks for the link - it looks like modules are an IDE fiction that has no direct correspondence with the deployed apk.

Comment: I would advice you to make a preemptive plan before things get "out of hand".